# Constructor with template argument deduction executes unexpected

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

**Problem**

The called constructor (That is, `A::A(T)`) does not execute as I expected. Calling it does compile (using GCC-8.3.0), but does not seem to execute the `std::cout operator<<`. Why is this?

**Code**

```
struct A {

    template <typename T>
    constexpr A(T) {
        std::cout << "A::A(T)";
    }
};

struct B {};

int main() {
    ::A a (B());
}
```

**Why would you even do this?**

I'm trying to deduce type `T` through *template argument deduction*. The object is irrelevant and therefore unnamed. I require type `T` to access certain data at compile-time (Among other things for `static_assert`). In C++, it is impossible to explicitly specify a *template argument* as constructor parameter, as far as I'm aware of. (So: `A a = A::A<T>`). I could do this in an indirect way, that is, creating a static member-function for creation, where the parameter can be specified:

```
struct C {
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr C create() { 
        // do whatever you want with T
        return C(); 
    }
};
```

However, I'm mostly just experimenting.

Comment: `::A a (B());` declares a function called "a", which takes a parameter-less (and unnamed) function that returns a `B`, and returns an `A`. (There are many potential duplicates, but I can't pick a good one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've came across the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You should define `a` like this instead:

```
::A a {B{}};
```